# SSRS Custom format with 2 decimal places for Y axis labels

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I have a rdl report which has a chart. I would like to set one or zero decimal places depending on a report parameter so I perform the following:

Right Click on the axis chart Report Item -> Properties -> Number -> Custom and I provide below expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!vtype.Value=1,"N1","N0")
```

but in design view, axis labels displays this expression instead of values formatted.

If I set below expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!vtype.Value=1,Format(Parameters!vtype.Value, "#,##0.#"),Format(Parameters!vtype.Value, "#,##0"))
```

I get the same, labels displays with this expression as text.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the Y axis in your chart.

[image]

Go to Vertical Axis properties, select Number tab and custom, in custom format textbox use your first expression.

[image]

```
=IIF(Parameters!vtype.Value=1,"N1","N0")
```

If you select 1 in your parameter it should use "N1" format.

It is normal Visual Studio shows the format expression for the label axis:

[image]

At runtime it shows the expected format:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, this it what I do, but after set first expression and click on accept button in the dialog window, chart shows y values with the text of the expression in design mode. Is it normal that in design mode Y labels are shown with the text of the expression? all y values display as =IIF(Parameters!vtype.Value=1,"N1","N0"). My parameter has a default value.

Comment: @user1624552, did you run the report? While designing, VS doesn't know the value or format for the label so it shows the expression.

Comment: Ok, perfect. I had not run the report yet. I didn't know that this behavior was normal in vs design mode for chart. So thanks for confirm me that this is normal in VS design mode. Thanks Alejandro!